# Uncaught ReferenceError: copiedElement is not defined

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться

```js
const copyElement = (elementId, elementObj) => {
  if (elementObj) {
    const copiedElement = elementObj
  } else {
    const copiedElement = selectedElements.filter(element => element.id === elementId)
  }

  let element;

  element = {
    ...copiedElement[0],
    id: generateElementId()
  }

  if (selectedElements === winds || selectedElements === areas) {
    element.params = copiedElement[0].params
  }

  if (selectedElements === groups) {
    copiedElement.elements.forEach((el) => {
      elements.elements.push(copyElement(el.id, el))
    })

  }

  if (elementObj) {
    if (elementObj.params) {
      if ('forse' in el.params) {
        winds.push(element)
      } else if ('coup' in el.params) {
        areas.push(element)
      }
    } else {
      winds.push(element)
    }
    return element
  } else {
    selectedElements.push(element)
    renderAll()
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="game-panel-item__copy" onClick="copyElement(${group.id})">
  Copy
</button>
```

Comment: замени `const` на `var`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//if (elementObj){
//    const copiedElement = elementObj
//}
//else{
//    const copiedElement = selectedElements.filter(element => element.id === elementId)
//}
const copiedElement = elementObj? [elementObj] : selectedElements.filter(element => element.id === elementId);
```

Comment: теперь Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined ошибку выводить

Comment: @Mbreti Очень плохо.